# Выключение DispatcherTimer в любом окне wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как произвести остановку таймера, запущенного в одном viewmodel в другом viewmodel?

Основной viewmodel

```
class MainWindow {
    public void SetTimer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Application.Current.Windows[0].Close();
    }
}
```

Дочерний viewmodel

```
class ChildWindow{
     public void DoSomething(){
         // что-то происходит
         // тут должен выключаться таймер
     }
}
```

В общем идея такова, я включаю таймер в одном окне и при нажатии кнопки открывается новое окно, в котором таймер, открытый в первом окне должен выключаться

Comment: Может быть можно передать во `ViewModel` экземпляр класса `DispatcherTimer` из основного `ViewModel`. Просто в момент создания и инициализации дочернего `ViewModel`. Приведите немного кода, чтобы можно было дать более конкретный ответ. Есть способы связи моделей`ViewModel` http://stackoverflow.com/a/5732844/5275890

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего вызвать на таймере `Stop`:

```
DispatcherTimer timer;
public void SetTimer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    timer.Start();
}

public void StopTimer()
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```